# How to isolate pty buffers created with socat and tee from tty?

Tags: linux, tty, tee, pty, socat

I'm trying to clone a tty that is connected to a serial device, so that I can have two programs reading the data simultaneously (one program occasionally writes to the serial device as well).

I'm using socat to clone the tty, which works fine:

`socat /dev/ttyACM0 SYSTEM:'tee >(socat - "PTY,rawer,link=/tmp/myPTY1") | socat - "PTY,rawer,link=/tmp/myPTY2"'`

However, these PTYs are not isolated. When myPTY1 doesn't get read, after some time myPTY2 won't receive any new data. Only when I then read from myPTY1 (clearing all the buffered data) then myPTY2 receives new data. I suspect this is about how socat buffers data, it seems like both PTYs are connected to the same buffer.

I would like both PTYs to be completely isolated, so that when one PTY doesn't get read (buffer runs full), the other isn't stuck, but continues receiving new data. Any idea how to do this?

I tried some socat options like nonblock, wait-slave, ctty but none have the desired effect.